# How to submit a form from script

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a simple form:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="email.php">      
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />   
  <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
  <textarea name="text" id="msg" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" onclick="empty()"/>
</form>
```

and an `empty()` function for checking if all inputs are there:

```
function empty(){
    var x; var y; var z;
    x = document.getElementById("name").value;
    y = document.getElementById("email").value;
    z = document.getElementById("msg").value;
    if (x == "" || y == "" || z == "") {
        document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "All inputs must be present before submitting.";
        return false;
    }else{
         document.form.submit(); /*this doesn't work*/
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get the form to submit...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit a form using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416641/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

Comment: `document.form` is not a valid selector for your form. Try something like this `document.querySelector('#form').submit()` in your else part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the button type.  Try this:

```html
<script>
  function empty() {
    var x;
    var y;
    var z;
    x = document.getElementById("name").value;
    y = document.getElementById("email").value;
    z = document.getElementById("msg").value;
    if (x == "" || y == "" || z == "") {
      document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "All inputs must be present before submitting.";
      return false;  // the only reason this worked previously is that the input type was wrong so the form didn't submit
    } else {
      return true; // return true instead of trying to submit the form with js
    }
  }
</script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="email.php">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
  <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
  <textarea name="text" id="msg" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" onclick="return empty();" />
  <!-- change the button type to submit and return the value from the empty function (false will prevent the default action of the button - stop the form submitting, true will allow the form to submit) -->
</form>
<div id="errors"></div>
```

[Noticed this doesn't work as a snippet so this is it working in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryt3cxe6/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define name of the form.After define this form can be submit using javascript.

To check example you can follow this example-

```
<form name="myform" action="handle-data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is the solution of his problem with his code ?